# When does the keychain unlock itself?

Tags: snow-leopard, keychain

I am using the "lock when sleeping" preference of the login keychain. When I use my computer after wake up, as expected i have to enter my password when an application (such as the webbrowser or instant messenger) try to access a keychain entry. However, sometimes the login keychain is unlocked after entering the password, sometimes it remains locked and the application gets single-time access. What rule does that follow? System is up to date 10.6.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting that can lock the Keychain after a period of inactivity.  So if you have unlocked it after sleep and then find after a few minutes that it is locked, it probably means that this option is turned on.

[image]

It's also possible that on some items you haven't checked 'always remember' and so it is popping up the request for credentials via keychain.

You can also repair your keychain using [this guide](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/9081.html).

Comment: Autolock after timeout is deactivated. The behaviour is like this: I have the Keychain icon enabled in my menu bar. After the Mac wakes up from sleep it shows the lock closed. When an application tries do access a password now, the lock remains closed for some of them, for others the lock is opened afterwards! When its opened, also *other* applications can access the keychain without asking for the password. I just wonder how it is determined if the entire keychain is unlocked after entering the password or if only the item is unlocked

Comment: I do not find these settings on High Sierra ... not "Keychain access" preferences.